# RtlFreeHeap Invalid Address when freeing memory after passing pointer to external library method

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic, segments

Alright, so, this is a pretty odd one.

I'm dynamically allocating memory in C using malloc, then calling a method that's defined inside a library I've linked.

The issue I'm getting is the memory fails to be freed after I've called the method, but it's fine if I free it before calling that method.

Code:

```
unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*(sLen + 1));
pData[0] = CRITICAL_ERROR; // defined as 2
memcpy(pData+1, pBuf, sLen);
libwebsocket_write(pLws, pData, sLen + 1, LWS_WRITE_BINARY);
free(pData);
```

An unhandled exception gets thrown when I call `free(pData)`.

I've tried compiling the library against the same OS, arch, and build configuration (Release) as my application, but it didn't work.

EDIT: I just compared the pointer address before and after the libwebsocket_write call, and it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [documentation](http://jsk.pp.ua/knowledge/libwebsocket.html) which states that:

***buf*** , The data to send. For data being sent on a websocket connection (ie, not default http), this buffer MUST have LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING bytes valid BEFORE the pointer and an additional LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING bytes valid in the buffer after (buf + len). This is so the protocol header and trailer data can be added in-situ.

You do not provide this padding. Heap memory before the pointer which holds internal size of the mallocated buffer is being changed by the function call and then free fails.